# How can a Go program consume a static library (.a file) of other Go code?

Tags: go, static-libraries

I'm coming from the C world into the Go world.  C programs frequently make use of definitions (functions, etc.) that are in static libraries, which usually have a suffix of .a in Linux.

With Go I can easily build .go files into such a library:

```
go build -buildmode=archive -o <name>.a
```

But once built, how can I direct other Go programs to make use of what's in this library?

Comment: You don't. There is no real use for making an archive manually.

Comment: Why would you want that in Go? Just because it is common in C doesn’t mean it sensible in Go too.

Answer (score -2):

if you really want it you can download that .a file for example of library foo/bar and place it to `$GOROOT/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH/foo/`, though you still have to have source code of lib in your go path, problem is that there is no point in this as go compiles fast enough. You can save at most few seconds, or not even that as downloading a file can take more.